# Uncaught typerror: cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

When I click on this div I want it to show an error message saying that it's too expensive

I have tried changing the document.getElementByClassName into a variable, I didn't expect that to work though.

```
function hideError() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("errorMessage").style.display = "none";
}
function showError() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("errorMessage").style.display = "contents";
  setTimeout("hideError", 5000);
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a node list. You have to iterate through the list and update each element individually.

Comment: @randomSoul OK well the point is it's a *list* of nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close. The first issue, [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You will need to either iterate through this list or call `[0]` to get the first item.

Second, the call to `setTimeout` should be a function as the first argument (not a string): `setTimeout(hideError, 5000);`.

```js
function hideError() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("errorMessage")[0].style.display = "none";
}

function showError() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("errorMessage")[0].style.display = "contents";
  setTimeout(hideError, 5000);
}

showError();
```

```html
<div class="errorMessage">ERROR</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns live `HTMLCollection`. To add style to individual element apply loop. Also `setTimeout` expects first parameter as `callback` function and not string.

```js
function hideError() {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName('errorMessage')].forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
}

function showError() {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName('errorMessage')].forEach(e => e.style.display = "contents");
    setTimeout(hideError, 5000);
}
```